# how to convert all to lowercase user names in Active directory

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I am trying to get our subversion configuration management repository to work with active directory. At the moment I am having a problem with some users having mixed case user names in active directory.

Would it be possible to change all users with mixed case user names to be all lowercase instead?

I'm using Windows Server 2003 Active Directory with 64 bit domain controller running on Windows 2000 mixed functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Write a script to change the properties of your ldap userobjects. Any scripting language with ldap functions will should work. VBS is commonly used but py should be just as easy or easier.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34024702/changing-username-in-active-directory-using-vbscript.aspx